# I can't figure out how to implement the display of elements in various actions. Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to implement a calendar whose initial state is the current week. Below this calendar there is a button that you can pull and then the user should change the weekly calendar to a monthly calendar. I don't quite understand how to implement during deployment so that the corresponding weeks are displayed with the appropriate deployment range. For example, the 3rd week of the current month is going on, it turns out that when the user starts to expand the weekly calendar, he should see how the first week appears, then the second week, the third week did not disappear anywhere and remained static and has already been 4 weeks[image][image][image]

In fact, I'm trying to implement this through the SliverAppBar, since in addition to this, I also have a list of entities on this screen. What comes to mind is to use Ani,atedContainer6, but it's not entirely clear how to achieve the animation I need. Therefore, I ask for help in which direction should I move